# Need help closing control panel

Tags: c#, windows, registry, controlpanel

Because I am doing certain tasks that need the control panel to be closed if it is open. Killing explorer is not the solution I am looking for as it is also closes the file explorer. I need a general solution that will work across different system languages. Will help if the solution is a c# code.

I have already tried closing **control panel** using `window.close()` which will work if the system language is **English** (I cannot compare `title=="Control panel"` because if the system language is suppose German, then control panel is called something different), as I am doing `window.title == "Control Panel"`. This is not a solution. I need some way to close it that will work on all systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the shell to run a command line such as:

```
taskkill control.exe
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to do a lil magic to do this.

You may need to first check the system language:

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`

and keep a list of strings that match "control panel" in all (or the most likely) languages in a collection, then do the compare for the window title in the matching language.

As far as actually closing the Control Panel once you have the match, since the Control Panel is actually part of Explorer.exe, killing it's process my have undesired consequences. However, (and it may be a bit ugly to the user) if you `SendKeys` the equivalent of `Alt + F4` to that window, it'll close just that window.

This is just one idea; `WM_CLOSE` may or may not work as well, rather than the `SendKeys` idea.